# Setter not generated on a transient field

Tags: jpa, lombok

I have a class annotated with Lombok @Data.

Setters are generated for all fields except one which is annotated with JPA @Transient.

I have tried to force the generation of the setter by adding @Setter for this field but no effect.

How can I force the generation of the setter for this field?

Comment: It always helps to see the relevant code. I would guess you are using a `final` modifier - in which case Lombok will never generate a setter. This has nothing to do with `@Transient`.

Comment: I am not using a final modifier but you are right this has nothing to do with @Transient. I had left <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument> in the configuration of maven-compiler-plugin in the pom.xml... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had left `<compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>` in the configuration of maven-compiler-plugin in the pom.xml.